# How do I get the text to automatically wrap in last row of this LaTeX table as shown?

Tags: tables

[image: The last row should wrap as shown in the image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headsepline,12pt,toc=index,
toc=bibliography,ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Method}}                                               & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Non-frictional  Parallelepiped\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Non-frictional  Knight\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Frictional  Knight\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{2-7} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1880 Experimental Cases}                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{21357 Experimental Cases}                                                           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{21357 Experimental Cases}                                                       \\ \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Modified  NEW Method \end{tabular}} & Final Quality                                                                        & Time (s)        & Final Quality                                                                     & Time (s)   & Final Quality                                                                   & Time (s) \\ \cline{2-7} 
            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.200 in 30 samples  with pop size 400\end{tabular}        & 35.0            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.126 in 20 samples  with pop. size 200\end{tabular}    & 63.8       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.146 in 20 samples  with pop. size 200\end{tabular}  & 368.8    \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}

}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I need  the last row entries to automatically wrap  as shown in the image.

Comment: The short answer is: don't use the `c` column specifier. You need to specify the width of the columns using something like `p{<width>}`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Jon. But, I would like the full table to automatically span the textwidth of that page. So wouldn't the width specification for each of the columns need a few/some/lot of guesses to get the total table width to the text span ?

Comment: That's why I said 'like `p{<width>}`. As you didn't specify clearly in your question all of your requirements, one would have to guess as to your unstated requirements. The minimalist choice is a `p`-column; a more complex solution is (e.g.) an `X` column from `tabularx`. (As Mico did [+1].)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you use a `tabularx` environment with 7 equal-width columns. This lets you dispense with all those internal `tabular` environments. This approach also dispenses with the need for a `\resizebox` instruction just to make the tabular material fit inside the width of the textblock. The result of taking this approach is shown in the first table below.

In a variation on this theme, you could decide it's not necessary (or even desirable) to make all columns have equal width. Instead, you might decide, say, that the "Final Quality" columns should be three times as wide as the "Time" Columns. This, too, can be handled with a `tabularx` environment, as the second table below shows. The second `tabularx` environment differs from the first only in the setup line. Whereas the first is defined via

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
```

the second has the following, more involved definition:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|*{3}{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C|}}
```

In combination with a switch to `\footnotesize`, this approach would appear to achieve your desired format.

Either of these approaches seems far superior to using `\resizebox` and ending up with super-tiny letters; cf the third table, which shows the result of your original code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headsepline,12pt,toc=index,
               toc=bibliography,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx,multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{Equal-width columns, \texttt{\string\normalsize}} \label{label-one}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
\hline
\textbf{Method} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{\bfseries Non-frictional Parallelepiped} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{\bfseries Non-frictional Knight} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{\bfseries Frictional Knight} \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{1880 Experimental Cases} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{21357 Experimental Cases} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{21357 Experimental Cases}  \\ 
\hline
Mod.\ new Method
& Final Quality  & Time (s)        
& Final Quality  & Time (s)   
& Final Quality  & Time (s) \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
& 0.200 in 30~samples with pop.\ size 400 & 35.0  
& 0.126 in 20~samples with pop.\ size 200 & 63.8       
& 0.146 in 20~samples with pop.\ size 200 & 368.8 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\footnotesize
\caption{Unequal-width columns, \texttt{\string\footnotesize}} \label{label-two}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|
   *{3}{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C|}}
 \hline
 \textbf{Method} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{\bfseries Non-frictional Parallelepiped} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{\bfseries Non-frictional Knight} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{\bfseries Frictional Knight} \\ 
 \cline{2-7} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{1880 Experimental Cases} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{21357 Experimental Cases} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{21357 Experimental Cases}  \\ 
 \hline
 Mod.\ new Method
 & Final Quality  & Time (s)        
 & Final Quality  & Time (s)   
 & Final Quality  & Time (s) \\ 
 \cline{2-7} 
 & 0.200 in 30~samples with pop.\ size 400 & 35.0  
 & 0.126 in 20~samples with pop.\ size 200 & 63.8       
 & 0.146 in 20~samples with pop.\ size 200 & 368.8 \\ 
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\caption{Original solution, with \texttt{\string\resizebox}}\label{label-three}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Method}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Non-frictional  Parallelepiped\end{tabular}}} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Non-frictional  Knight\end{tabular}}} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Frictional  Knight\end{tabular}}} \\ 
        \cline{2-7} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1880 Experimental Cases}                                                                    
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{21357 Experimental Cases}                                                           
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{21357 Experimental Cases}                                                       
        \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Modified  NEW Method \end{tabular}} 
        & Final Quality & Time (s) 
        & Final Quality & Time (s)   
        & Final Quality & Time (s) \\ 
        \cline{2-7} 
        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.200 in 30 samples  with pop size 400\end{tabular}        & 35.0            
        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.126 in 20 samples  with pop. size 200\end{tabular}    & 63.8       
        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.146 in 20 samples  with pop. size 200\end{tabular}  & 368.8    \\ 
        \hline
        \end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mico for a comprehensive solution. Yes, indeed the second option is the desirable one. A minor issue, though, 'Non-frictional  Knight" and "Frictional Knight" in the top row would look better as wrapped. But, I guess I may need to enforce it specifically with \\, isn't it ?

Comment: Or at least couldn't the 'Non-frictional Knight" and "Frictional Knight" in the top row be centre-aligned within the respective cells instead of the top-aligned as it looks now (also for the "Method" and "Mod. New Method" in their cells) ?

Comment: @user119142 - Have you tried providing the instruction `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` in the preamble?

Comment: @user119142 - By the way, I don't have the slightest clue what non-frictional parallelepipeds and frictional and non-frictional knights are. That said, your table is neither particularly well designed nor all that clear. It contains a jumble of (probably highly relevant and important!) information, but it's lacking structure to show how the various items are related to each other. If you have a choice between working on (a) achieving better vertical centering of some cell contents or (b) clarifying the table's structure and information content, I'd like to urge you to choose the latter task.